# Exception method name thrown in TPL Dataflow block is always MoveNext()

Tags: c#, exception, methods, async-await, task-parallel-library

I'm trying to get most inner method name of exception stacktrace in example below. For an unknown reason I always get `MoveNext` method name, not real name. How can I solve it?

```
var st = new StackTrace(ex, true);
var frame = st.GetFrames()?.First(y => y.GetFileName() != null);
var method = frame.GetMethod().ToString(); // result: Void MoveNext()
var method2 = frame.Name; // result: MoveNext
```

**UPDATE:**

That happens when exception is thrown in a `TPL Dataflow` Block's delegate:

```
private async Task Parse(ListItem item)
{
    await Task.Delay(1);
    throw new Exception("Error");
}
```

//...

```
var parseBlock = new ActionBlock<ListItem>(
                    async x => { await Parse(x).ConfigureAwait(false); });
```

I get `MoveNext` from any block with any delegate. Stacktrace:

```
at RP.Core.ListsPipeline.<Parse>d__21.MoveNext() in Class.cs:line 179
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
at Class.<<Start>b__18_0>d.MoveNext() in Class.cs:line 81
```

I want to get `Parse` method name (first string of StackTrace).

Comment: Show us the code that triggered the exception.

Comment: The posted code is "how to get exception info" and is unnecessary.

Comment: Also post the exact exception details (from the debugger windows).

Comment: You already get the name, of at least the name the async/await transformations left you. Your method has become a 'state-machine' (a class) and MoveNext() is its main method.

Comment: In other words, this is 'by design'.

Comment: Ok. So is there a way to extract `<Parse>` word from StackTrace?

Comment: Of course there is, with some easy RegEx.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This:

```
private async Task Parse(ListItem item)
{
    await Task.Delay(1);
    throw new Exception("Error");
}
```

Gets translated into this:

```
private Task Parse()
{
    Program.<Parse>d__0 <Parse>d__;
    <Parse>d__.<>t__builder = AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Create();
    <Parse>d__.<>1__state = -1;
    AsyncTaskMethodBuilder <>t__builder = <Parse>d__.<>t__builder;
    <>t__builder.Start<Program.<Parse>d__0>(ref <Parse>d__);
    return <Parse>d__.<>t__builder.Task;
}
```

And the actual invocation of your method is inside the state-machine's `MoveNext()` method created by the compiler. This effectively means that the code isn't invoked inside `Parse()`. That's why you're seeing `MoveNext` as the method name, and that is why you *won't be able* to get `Parse` as the method name.

Answer (score 1):

To solve your problem explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31378010/6254070) answer, get the name from the exception stacktrace by Regex:

`new Regex(@"\<(.*?)\>").Match(myException.StackTrace).ToString().Trim('>','<');`

instead of

`myException.TargetSite.Name.ToString()`